# How can I put a stress accent (a right-slanted accent) on an arbitrary character?

Tags: accents

Is there a command for adding a stress symbol above any arbitrary vowel?

I do not see how this can be the duplicate of the question re how to typeset accented characters, as this one is regarding putting a stress on top of an arbitrary vovel. I should not have to need to worry about whether there is or there is not an accented character out there for any given vowel - if it requires a stress, there should be a way to add it.

**Edit**

I thought I could achieve this with `$\acute{}$` but the accent is being added to the very right top corner of the character instead of the top middle of it.

Comment: Dou you mean like the result of  `\'o`?

Comment: For example, two possibilities: `Bl\'o-feld or Blo$'$-feld`

Comment: I do not know whether I mean anything like `\'o` as when I put `\'` in front of the letters where I need an accent, I get this error: `Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \global (U+2DD)(inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX. ...zzzzz\'`

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes This seems to work w/o Babel and in English only, but not for other languages.

Comment: If you are using Unicode, then `Bl\symbol{"00F3}-feld` would work, though you should be able to produce a direct representation of the character in your input, as well.  For example, I can type `Bló-feld`, where the accented o is achieved directly on my windows machine as ALT 162.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Are you trying to help me with an accented `o`? How should this work with any arbitrary vovel in any arbitrary language?

Comment: You have to know the unicode representation for those vowels: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters

Comment: Use a proper OpenType font with combining characters and LuaTeX or XeLaTeX, and enter the characters directly in your source.

Comment: This would require incredible amount of research and effort. So, to sum it up, is there no simple way to add a stress symbol to an arbitrary character in an arbitrary language?

Comment: `Bl\stackon[.2pt]{o}{$\scriptscriptstyle\prime$}-feld (stackengine v1)

Bl\stackon[-4pt]{o}{\'{}}-feld (stackengine v2)` with `stackengine` package.  This does not require you to know the unicode for the accented letter in advance, as long as you can produce the base letter.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Excellent! Works with any language, any character!

Comment: For a more general use (since `\stackon` defaults, if changed, could wreak havoc), you might choose to codify it this way: `\newcommand\myac[3][.5pt]{\stackengine{#1}{#2}{#3}{O}{c}{F}{F}{S}}`, with comparable usage like `\myac[.2pt]{o}{$\scriptscriptstyle\prime$}`, etc.  Good luck!

Comment: There is a Unicode "combining accute accent" character that can be added to any other character. So there's no major lookup required.